# CSS Transition delay in and out?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want to fade an item in using `opacity` and set its `visibility` accordingly, once the opacity transition is done.

Consider this code:

```
.menu {
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-out 0s, visibility 0s ease 0.25s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.menu.open {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

This menu pops straight in, due to the 0.25s delay on visibility, but fades out correctly.

I want it to fade both in and out, but I can't find a way to set a delay function to the visibility property separately for *in* **and** *out* transitions. Is this even possible?

So ideally, I want to tell visibility to have a `0s` delay to start and then a `0.25s` delay to end, but it seems I can only set one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your item is no longer visible. As you're delaying the `visibility` transition, your item will get its `opacity` changed, without this change being visible. Then (0.25s later), the `visibility` transition begin... but your item has already an `opacity: 1`.

You should remove the transition delay/duration for `visibility` when item is showing:

```js
$(document).on('click', function(event) { $('.menu').toggleClass('open'); });
```

```css
.menu {
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-out 0s, visibility 0s ease 0.25s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.menu.open {
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="menu open">My menu</nav>
```